# Autoloading model on demand in codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, model

Can I somehow omit the first line? i.e. `$this->load->model('Model_name');` and autoload it when necessary?

To load a model you will use the following function:

```
$this->load->model('Model_name');
```

Once loaded, you will access your model functions using an object with the same name as your class:

```
$this->Model_name->function();
```

Comment: "autoload it when necessary" is an oxymoron. You either autoload it _or_ you load it when necessary (on demand). What do yo want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy loading is not supported in Codeiginiter 2.1

There are a couple of options available to you

1. Use the 'autoload' in the config. This will always make the model available throughout the application. [See here for more info](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html)
2. Load the model in the __construct() of your controller (if it is specific to that controller)

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand the logic .

```
$this->load->model('Model_name') means you load it when it necessary.
```

or

If you find that you need a particular model globally throughout your application, you can tell CodeIgniter to auto-load it during system initialization. This is done by opening the application/config/autoload.php file and adding the model to the autoload array.